# Android Slide in a Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a Menu that slides in from right to left. The sliding menu is done, also a Button that triggers the Slidein/out.

Now i want to animate the Button too. Currently i let it move by setting Margin, but thats ugly because its jumping like hell... Is there any simple way to attach the Button to the Menu? Or any simple way to animate it?

The Menu is a LinearView in a RelativeView. The RelativeView contains the Button.
[image: On the top left the Trigger button]

Answer (score 0):

best way to do that is to use nineoldandroids library. [here](http://nineoldandroids.com/) is the link and you can see in usage section how you can do it.